# Can someone explain this block of Python code?

Tags: python, while-loop, integer

> Write a program that asks the user to enter an integer and prints two integers, `root` and `pwr`, such that `0 < pwr < 6` and `root**pwr` is equal to the integer entered by the user. If no such such pair of integers exists, it should print a message to that effect.

I have the answer to the question (through Google), but I am having trouble understanding it, can someone offer a line by line explanation to the execution of the code?

```
num = int(raw_input('Enter a positive integer: ')) 
pwr = 2 
root = 1
ans = ''
while pwr < 6: 
    while root**pwr <= num:
        if root**pwr == num:       
            print 'the root is ',root,
            print 'the power is ', pwr
            ans = True
        root += 1        
    pwr += 1
    root = 1
if ans != True:
    print'No such pair of integers exist'
```

Answer (score 2):

Essentially it has 2 loops in which it simply tries every possible option until the two numbers `root` and `pwr` are found (brute force).

```
#get input
num = int(raw_input('Enter a positive integer: '))
#initialize variables
pwr = 2
root = 1
ans = ''
#exhaustively try each possible exponent from 0 to 6
while pwr < 6:
    #exhaustively try each base until overshooting or finding the answer
    while root**pwr <= num: 
        if root**pwr == num: #found
            print 'the root is ',root,
            print 'the power is ', pwr
            ans = True
        root += 1 #next base (note that the loop doesn't break, so all possible answers will be printed)
    pwr += 1 #next exponent
    root = 1 #reset base or you could immediately overshoot
if ans != True: #not found
    print'No such pair of integers exist'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had one more question, why is ans = ' '?

Comment: It just initializes `ans` to a value that doesn't evaluate to `True` (I just tested). Although personally I would have initialized it as `ans = False` just for readability/logic.

Comment: @AmanBhargava, I believe because one has to initialize this variable first since we're accessing it when the loop exits, but it's set only once during the loop.